# Как работать с datetime в angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Как работать с datetime в angularjs?
Я получаю дату и время в формате yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 
Как мне это конвертировать в формат - день-месяц- год  время?
Спасибо

Comment: [/ API Reference / ng / filter components in ng / date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.myDate = new Date;`

`{{myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}`